# Renaming Subdirectories and Files

Tags: bash, unix, directory

I have a script using a for loop that would rename folders and files. The script would take the list of files and folders and rename them conditionally. I would invoke the file using the command:

```
find test/* -exec ./replace.sh {} \;
```

My replace.sh script would contain something similar to:

```
for i in $@
mv $OLDFILE $NEWFILE
done
```

$OLDFILE and $NEWFILE has been set previously and I don't believe any problems will arise from them.

My problem arises when I hit upon subdirectories. Originally, I would have folders like:

```
folder_1

 -file1

 -file2
```

When my script changes folder_1 into folderX1, the next argument, folder_1/file1 woudl be invalid as the changed path would be folderX1/file1. I figured I could create a stack with a list of folders that is being changed and pop them out later to rename the files but this seems hard on bash. Is there a better method that I am missing?

P.S I could run the program several times to go through all the subdirectories but this doesn't seem efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `-depth` to the find command. This will process the directory's files before the directory itself. See [`man find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Your `find` usage is problematic.  The first option is the *start location* for the search, so you don't want to use a glob there.  If you want only the files in `test/` and not any of its subdirectories, use the `-depth` option, as Olaf suggested.

You don't really need to use a separate script to handle this rename.  It can be done within the `find` command line, if you don't mind a little mess.

To handle just the top-level of files, you could do this:

```
$ touch foo.txt bar.txt baz.ext
$ find test -depth 1 -type f -name \*.txt -exec bash -c 'f="{}"; mv -v "{}" "${f/.txt/.csv}"' \;
./foo.txt -> ./foo.csv
./bar.txt -> ./bar.csv
$
```

But your concern is valid -- `find` will build a list of matches, and if your `-exec` changes the list out from under `find`, some renames will fail.

I suspect your quickest solution is to do this in TWO stages (not several): one for files, followed by one for directories.  (Or change the order, I don't think it should matter.)

```
$ mkdir foo_1; touch red_2 foo_1/blue_3
$ find . -type f -name \*_\* -exec bash -c 'f="{}"; mv -v "{}" "${f%_?}X${f##*_}"' \;
./foo_1/blue_3 -> ./foo_1/blueX3
./red_2 -> ./redX2
$ find . -type d -name \*_\* -exec bash -c 'f="{}"; mv -v "{}" "${f%_?}X${f##*_}"' \;
./foo_1 -> ./fooX1
```

Bash parameter expansion will get you a long way.

Another option, depending on your implementation of `find`, is the `-d` option:

```
 -d      Cause find to perform a depth-first traversal, i.e., directories
         are visited in post-order and all entries in a directory will be
         acted on before the directory itself.  By default, find visits
         directories in pre-order, i.e., before their contents.  Note, the
         default is not a breadth-first traversal.
```

So:

```
$ mkdir -p foo_1/bar_2; touch red_3 foo_1/blue_4 foo_1/bar_2/green_5
$ find . -d -name \*_\* -exec bash -c 'f="{}"; mv -v "{}" "${f%_?}X${f##*_}"' \;
./foo_1/bar_2/green_5 -> ./foo_1/bar_2/greenX5
./foo_1/bar_2 -> ./foo_1/barX2
./foo_1/blue_4 -> ./foo_1/blueX4
./foo_1 -> ./fooX1
./red_3 -> ./redX3
$
```

Comment: You're right that the glob is unnecessary; you're wrong in that it is not harmful.  You can specify a list of places to search before you specify the search criteria.  For example: `find /work1 /work2 /work3 /work4 /work5 -name '*bug*' -type f` is fine, and could be abbreviated to `find /work[1-5] -name '*bug*' -type f`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - if there was a file whose name started with a hyphen, would `find` not consider that the beginning of its expression list?  While one can certainly specify multiple paths, doing so *accidentally* can never be good.

Comment: A name beginning with a dash would only matter if it was globed with a plain star.  If you do `./*` for example, it matters not that you have files like `-delete` in the directory.

Comment: Hmm, true.  Still, I'm hoping that `find`'s `-d` option is what the OP was looking for.  :-)